# LRU implementation in C++ using a LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

Explanation : I am adding new elements in the list until the window runs out. Head will have the earliest element and tail will have the most recent element. Once the window is over, every addition requires deletion of the very first element or least used in the list which was temporally inserted a lot earlier than other elements. An access to an existing page in the list brings it to the end of the list signifying most recent use.

List end represents most recent element in the cache.
List head represents earliest of all the elements in the cache.

`Link.h`

```
#ifndef LINKLIST_LINK_H
#define LINKLIST_LINK_H

#include <iosfwd>

class Link{
private:
    int value;
    Link* next = nullptr;
public:
    Link();

    explicit Link(int key);

    int getValue() const;

    void setValue(int value);

    Link *getNext() const;

    void setNext(Link *next);

    friend void operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Link &link);
};

#endif //LINKLIST_LINK_H
```

`Link.cpp`

```
#include "Link.h"

#include <iostream>

Link::Link()  {
}

Link::Link(int key) {
    this->setValue(key);
}

int Link::getValue() const {
    return value;
}

void Link::setValue(int value) {
    Link::value = value;
}


Link *Link::getNext() const {
    return next;
}

void Link::setNext(Link *next) {
    Link::next = next;
}

void operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Link &link){
    os<<link.getValue()<<" ";
}
```

`LinkList.h`

```
#ifndef LINKLIST_LINKLIST_H
#define LINKLIST_LINKLIST_H

#include <vector>
#include "Link.h"

class LinkList{

protected:
    Link* head = nullptr;

    Link* tail = nullptr;

    std::vector<void* >linksAddresses;
public:

    virtual ~LinkList();

    void insert(int key);

    void push_back(int key);

    void push_front(int key);

    bool deleteKey(int key);

    bool findKey(int key);

    void insert_sorted(int key);

    friend void operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkList &linkList);

    void getLinksAddresses();

    void printReverse() const;

    void do_reverse();

    Link* delete_at_pos(int n);
};

#endif //LINKLIST_LINKLIST_H
```

`LinkList.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkList.h"

void LinkList::insert(int key) {
    push_back(key);
}

void LinkList::push_front(int key) {

    Link *newNode = new Link(key);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
    }
    //std::cout << "Inserted " << key <<" address :  "<<&newNode << " at front\n";

}

void LinkList::push_back(int key) {
    Link *newNode = new Link(key);
    if (tail == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail->setNext(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
    }
    //std::cout << "Inserted " << key << " at back\n";

}

bool LinkList::deleteKey(int key) {
    Link *curr = head;
    Link *prev = head;

    if (head != nullptr && head->getValue() == key) {
        Link *temp = head;
        head = head->getNext();
        if(head == nullptr)
           tail = nullptr;
        delete temp;
        std::cout << "Deleted " << key << "\n";
        return true;
    }

    while (curr != nullptr && curr->getValue() != key) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }

    if (curr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "To delete Key " << key << " doesn't exist\n";
        return false;
    } else {
        prev->setNext(curr->getNext());
        delete curr;
        std::cout << "Deleted " << key << "\n";
        return true;
    }
}

bool LinkList::findKey(int key) {
    Link *current = head;
    while (current != nullptr && current->getValue() != key)
        current = current->getNext();
    return current != nullptr;
}

LinkList::~LinkList() {
    Link *next;
    Link *curr = head;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        next = curr->getNext();
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    //std::cout<<"Memory freed\n";
}

void operator<<(std::ostream &os, const LinkList &linkList) {
    Link *curr = linkList.head;
    os << "List is : ";
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        os << *curr;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
    os << '\n';
}

void LinkList::insert_sorted(int key) {
    //TODO
}

void LinkList::getLinksAddresses() {
    while (head != nullptr){
        linksAddresses.push_back(&head);
        std::cout<<&head<<" "<<head->getValue()<<"\n";
        head = head->getNext();
    }
}

void reverse(Link* head){
    if(head!= nullptr){
        reverse(head->getNext());
        std::cout<<head->getValue()<<" ";
    }
}

void LinkList::printReverse() const {
    reverse(head);
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

void LinkList::do_reverse() {

    Link* prev = nullptr;
    Link* curr = head;
    Link* next = curr->getNext();
    while (curr){

    }

}

Link* LinkList::delete_at_pos(int n)
{
    if(n <=0)
        return head;
    int count  = 1;
    Link* curr = head, *prev = nullptr;;
    while(curr!=nullptr){
        if(count == n)
            break;
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->getNext();
        count++;
    }
    if(curr!=nullptr){
        Link* temp = curr;
        if(curr == head){
            head = head->getNext();
        }else{
            prev->setNext(curr->getNext());
            }
        delete temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

`LRU.hpp`

```
#ifndef LINKLIST_LRU_HPP
#define LINKLIST_LRU_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "LinkList.h"
class LRU : public LinkList{
private:
    const int MAX = 4;
    int max_len  = 0;
    Link* findPage(int key){
        Link *current = LinkList::head;
        while (current != nullptr && current->getValue() != key)
            current = current->getNext();
        return current;
    }
public:
    void insert(int key) override{
        if(MAX > 0) {
            Link *page = findPage(key);
            if (page != nullptr) {
                access(page->getValue());
                return;
            }

            if (max_len >= MAX) {
                deleteKey(LinkList::head->getValue());
                max_len--;
            }
            push_back(key);
            max_len++;
        }
    }

    bool access(int key){
        Link *current = findPage(key);
        if(current == nullptr)
            return false;
        else{
            int val = current->getValue();
            deleteKey(val);
            max_len--;
            insert(val);
            return true;
        }
    }
};

#endif //LINKLIST_LRU_HPP
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "LinkList.h"
#include "LRU.hpp"
#include <iostream>
void testingLinkedLRU();
int main() {
    testingLinkedLRU();
    return 0;
}
void testingLinkedLRU(){
LRU lru;
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(1);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(2);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(3);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(4);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(5);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(6);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.access(3);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(-5);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(5);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.insert(50);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.access(5);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.access(1);
std::cout<<lru;

lru.access(-5);
std::cout<<lru;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is misleading that the same field in `Link` is sometimes referred as `key` and sometimes as `value`.
- `LRU::insert` works too hard.

  - It calls `findPage`, followed by `access`, which in turn calls

    - `findPage` *with the same argument*, and
    - `deleteKey`, which also traverses the list *looking for the same key*.

  Three traversals with the same argument seems excessive. Consider finding the page which *links to* the victim.
- A standard implementation of the linked list may exhibits an undesirable behavior. Continuous deletion and creation of nodes will eventually scatter the nodes all over the heap, leading to the poor referential locality, hence plenty of cache misses during traversal. Since your list by definition has a fixed number of entries, try to keep your `Link`s compactly, say in an array, and reuse them.
- `LinkList::push_front` shall be streamlined. `head = newNode` is executed in both branches; take it out of `if/else`:

  ```
      newNode->setNext(head);
      if (head == nullptr) {
          tail = newNode;
      }
      head = newNode;
  ```

  Ditto for `push_back`.
- I do not endorse trivial getters and setters. There are no invariants to protect, so they just add noise. Making `Link::key` and `Link::next` public is just as good.

Comment: For the insert method and access method I found some common code between them so I ended up grouping it  into a function. I guess I can change the access method to directly take the pointer and bring it to the end/front of the list. This way the access method need not call findPage. Also for optimizations I am gonna substitute the structures for hashtable + doubly linked list where the hash table will have the (key, memory_location) as an entry. this way we can look up and delte in O(1) time. I just wanted to implement a correctly behaving LRU first, irrespective of the time constraints.

Answer (score 4):

1. One class per file, and each with a dedicated header, is a pretty heavy-handed attempt at getting novices to modularize. As it is often the case, it is also counter-productive in this case.
2. `Link` is an internal implementation-detail of `LinkList` and derived classes, aside from unfortunately and inadvertently being exposed by `.delete_at_pos()`.

   Fix that one return, and make the class private.
3. As `Link` is an implementation-detail, there is no sense in trying and failing miserably to hide its details behind a dozen useless public members. Just expose them directly, the only one which *might* make sense to keep (though that is debatable) is the constructor.
4. Consider a more descriptive name for `LinkList`. Maybe `ForwardList`?
5. I wonder what `linksAddresses` is for, aside from taking up space.
6. There seems to be a lot of stubbed and half-done code left in `LinkList`. Other code is quite repetitive.
7. I suggest basing an LRU-cache on a `std::vector<T>` or if the items are heavy, a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. Also, just a single free function treating such a an LRU-cache might be good enough.
8. There is no reason to explicitly mention `nullptr` all the time for comparisons, this is C++ not Java or C#. Use `!` for negation as needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really useful thing to implement! Good choice of projects. Here are some thoughts on how you could improve it:

## Naming

Generally when I think of a linked list I don't think of a list of links. I think of a list of nodes which are linked to each other (via next and/or previous pointers). For  that reason, I wouldn't call your class `Link`, I'd call it `Node`. The link in your class is the `next` pointer.

The distinction between `push_back()` and `insert()` is unclear. In the base class there doesn't appear to be a difference as `insert()` simply calls `push_back()`. If I make an `LRU` object and call `push_back()` what are the consequences? (Or `push_front()` for that matter?) Perhaps `LRU` shouldn't make the methods of `LinkList` public. Also, renaming `insert()` to `add_new_cache_item()` would make clear which a caller should be using given a particular use case.

Related method names should follow the same pattern. You have `insert()` but then its opposite is called `deleteKey()`. Presumably that's because `delete` is a keyword so you couldn't call it that. I'd either rename `insert()` to `insertKey()` or rename `deleteKey()` to simply `remove()`.

## Do you need `setValue`?

Is there a reason why you need a `setValue()` method in `Link`? It's only called from the constructor. You could simply move the code for it into the constructor and get rid of the public function. (If you added a `next` parameter to the constructor you could make the class immutable which is helpful for multithreading, though it would involve changing some of the logic of updating the list.)

## Encapsulation

I don't generally like `friend` functions. People will say that `operator<<()` is always a `friend` function. But here you're careful to keep the `Link` parameter `const` and it only calls the (also `const`) `getValue()` method. There's nothing  here that requires it be a `friend` function, so I say get rid of the `friend` designation. Just make it a free function in the header.

## Double-ended Queue

What you've created actually has a name other than "linked list". It's often called a [double-ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) or `deque` for short. They have several useful characteristics such as being O(1) for insertion and deletion at the ends, as you've no doubt discovered. There is a standard container called `std::deque` that implements this. (Though I realize you tagged this as "reinventing the wheel", which is always good for learning!)

## Avoid raw pointers

I agree with others that you could implement this with a `vector` or `array` (or `deque`) if you wanted to. But whatever you do, you should avoid using raw pointers. They have so many potential pitfalls that they're really not worth it. I recommend using either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on the situation. They help avoid a large class of resource management errors.

## Symmetry

You should strive to make the interface for your classes symmetrical to make them easier to use and understand. By that I mean that if you have an `insert()` method that does one thing, the `remove()` or `delete()` method should do the opposite. In `LRU` you've overridden `insert()` to do things like increment the `max_len` counter. But then in `access()` you have to manually decrement it after calling `deleteKey()`. You should also override `deleteKey()` to call the base class and decrement `max_len`  so that someone updating `access()` doesn't have to know this fact in the future. They can simply call `deleteKey()` and not worry about it.